# Can i give two class attributes to an HTML element. İf so, which effects my page if i write code to both of them?

Tags: html, css

I wonder which selecter will be affecting my div and why?

**HTML**

```
 <div class="div-1" class="div-2"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div-1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: gray;
}

.div-2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
.div-1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.div-2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1" class="div-2"></div>
```

Comment: Try it in the snippet, the first one will be used.

Comment: It should be `class="div-1 div-2"` - and if so then both with the last rule overriding anything that comes before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When parsing the start tag, the second `class` attribute will trigger a [duplicate attribute parse error](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parse-error-duplicate-attribute) and be ignored.

> if there is already an attribute on the token with the exact same name, then this is a duplicate-attribute parse error and the new attribute must be removed from the token.

Consequently only the first `class` attribute will be added so the only class that will apply to the div is `div-1` and thus only the first ruleset will apply.

Note that you can apply multiple classes to a single element since the `class` attribute accepts a *space-separated **list** of classes*. In that case, the normal rules for [the cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade) will apply (with the properties of the second rule-set overriding the duplicate properties of the first because the selectors have equal *specificity* and so they are applied in order of appearance).